# php page array variable - htaccess request_uri rewriteRule

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a little index file with a page array, and a variable so I don't have to keep adding lines to the array, every time a page is added.

```
$geturi = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; // /about
$geturi = preg_replace('/^./' , '' , $geturi); // change to about
$geturi = strtolower($geturi);

$pages = array ( 
  'home' => array('name' => 'home' , 'title' => 'County Road' , 'page' => 'incdoc/default'),
  "$geturi" => array('name' => "$geturi", 'title' => "$geturi" , 'page' => "incdoc/$geturi"),
  '403' => array('name' => '403' , 'title' => '403 Forbidden' , 'page' => 'incdoc/403'),
  '404' => array('name' => '404' , 'title' => '404 Not Found' , 'page' => 'incdoc/404')
);

if (isset ($_GET['p'])) {
  $pageID = $_GET['p'];
  if (! isset($pages[$pageID])) $pageID = 404;
}
else { 
  $pageID = 'home';
}
define('this_page', $pages[$pageID]['name']);
```

In the htaccess file a RewriteRule to change the page link (?p=about) to (/about). But I have to add a line for every page.

```
RewriteRule ^about/?$ ?p=about  [NC]
```

Is there a way to make a variable for %{request_uri} and use it in  the htaccess file. So I don't have to add a line every time I add a page?

```
RewriteRule ^$uri/?$ ?p=$uri  [NC]
```

I tried different syntax, put I can't figure out mod_rewrite. %{request_uri}.

Comment: Yep, it looks something like `^(.*)$ index.php?p=$1 [QSA,L]`

Comment: You should not primarily try around to learn the syntax of the directives you want to use in your configuration. Instead you want to work through one or two tutorials and, _more important_ , you want to bookmark the documentation of the apache modules you are using, because that is where you clearly get shown the syntax you are trying to find: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html

Comment: You certainly _could_ implement a logic to modify the ".htaccess" configuration file each time you have a change in your setup. Some wide spread frameworks do that, wordpress for example. That however is a HUGE security issue, once you start to think about it: a software should _never_ be able to alter itself. For obvious reasons. Instead you should rewrite _all_ such requests to a single routing script which performs the rewriting you want not on protocol level but inside your application logic. That is the approach you should prefer.